# "npm run dev" doesn't do anything anymore after NPM update to 8.10

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-9

I updated NPM to the latest version and now, while it doesn't return an error, "npm run dev" doesn't update the code anymore. I have to keep running the command in the terminal in order for the code to change in the app. I'm using Laravel + Vue. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: "_I have to keep running the command in the terminal_" `npm run dev` is a "one-time" command, use `npm run watch` to compile assets when the source changes

Comment: You're right. I am sorry, I forgot on the moment. Though I had some odd errors while running "npm run dev", two warnings  `autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.` and `Child mini-css-extract-plugin` and after running 'npm run watch' they dissappeared